# get second URL parameter in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to pass parameters in the URL

this is my URL after I pass it using javascript

```js
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
  
    //this == the link that was clicked
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var url = new URL(href);
var c = url.searchParams.get("product");
window.location.href = 'https://ngisrael.co.il/?page_id=9051/name='+c+''

    return false;
});
          

https://ngisrael.co.il/?page_id=9051/name=theval
```

when I am trying to get the name parameter with javascript I get a null but with the same code I can get the page_id

if I am trying to this in the URL
https://ngisrael.co.il/?page_id=9051&name=theval the parameter name is no showing in the URL

any help?